# Unknown fonts in mysql database

Tags: mysql, fonts, hindi

How to reproduce unknown fonts to correct hindi font in mysql database?
i have database contains hindi field and now the fonts are not showing correctly it shows

```
**Ã Â¤Â­Ã Â¤Â¾Ã Â¤Â°Ã Â¤Â¤Ã Â¥â‚¬Ã Â¤Â¯**
```

how to convert this font?
thanks

Comment: please set the collation of your mysql table to utf8_unicode_ci. The page where you display fonts add the following line
< meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Answer (score 0):

I also once faced the same problem in which I used `$con->set_charset("utf8");` right before the query.